# qml listview improve speed of changing items

Tags: qt, qml

i have a listview, how to change a speed of changing items, tried highlightMoveSpeed(highlightMoveDuration), but that does not working
Is there any way to increase the spped

**slider.qml**

```
import QtQuick 1.0

Rectangle {
id: slider
anchors.fill: parent

Component {
    id: pageDelegate

    Rectangle {
        id: page

        height: parent.height



        Component.onCompleted: page.width = slider.width

        Rectangle { 
            anchors.fill: parent
            // anchors.margins: 15

            Image{
                anchors.top: parent.top
                anchors.fill: parent
                source: modelData
            }   
        }
    }
}

ListView {
    id: list_model
    anchors.fill: parent
    model: modelData
    delegate: pageDelegate
    orientation: ListView.Horizontal
    snapMode: ListView.SnapToItem
    spacing: 5
    highlightMoveSpeed: 10000000
}
```

}

Comment: did you try setting `highlightFollowsCurrentItem : true` when you were using the manual highlight speed?

Comment: i'm a lil stupid, thanks, it's working now

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the default highlight and set its speed, e.g.

```
highlightMoveDuration : 200
highlightMoveVelocity : 1000
```

or, in case you use your custom highlight, let the highlight component handle the behaviour. E.g.

```
// Set the highlight delegate. Note we must also set highlightFollowsCurrentItem
// to false so the highlight delegate can control how the highlight is moved.
highlightFollowsCurrentItem: false
highlight: Rectangle {
    y: myListView.currentItem.y;
    Behavior on y {
        SmoothedAnimation {
            easing.type: Easing.Linear
            duration:200;
            maximumEasingTime:300
            velocity : 1000
        }
    }
}
```

Check the [qt highlight example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-views-listview-highlight-qml.html)

Answer (score 0):

A note about the other highlight move property: if you want to use `highlightMoveDuration` instead of `highlightMoveVelocity` (`highlightMoveSpeed` in Qt 4), you need to set the latter to -1:

```
highlightMoveDuration: 1000
highlightMoveVelocity: -1
```